# Checking that the background image has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```
$('<div>')
    .css('background-image', 'url(' + images[imageToLoad].url + ') no-repeat center center')
    .appendTo('#image-container')
    .hide()
    .load(function () {
        loadedImages.push($(this));
    });
```

Somehow the `load` event never triggers here when the background image has loaded. What event should I capture to know when the background has loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @variant said + code since the img onload event doesn't always fire:

```
var img = new Image(),
    div = $( "<div>" ).appendTo( "#image-container").hide();        

img.onload = function(){
    if( this.isLoaded ) {
    return;
    }
this.isLoaded = true;
loadedImages.push( 
    div.css( "background-image", "url('"+this.src+"') no-repeat center center" )
    );
}

img.src = images[imageToLoad].url;

if( ( img.complete || img.readyState === 4 ) && !img.isLoaded ) {
img.onload();
}
```

Comment: The img onload event doesn't always fire, even using the jQuery `.load()`? Could you please expand upon this?

Comment: When you do `.load()` on a div, it makes an ajax call completely irrelevant to your problem: http://api.jquery.com/load/. The img.onload function doesn't usually automatically fire if the image is in cache which is why the explicit call is made.

Answer (score 1):

There is no event to capture here.

What you can do is preload the image using an `IMG` tag and listen to `load` event on it. When it is fired append your div with background-image to the DOM. The image is already in the browser's cache and the loading will be instantaneous.